# wake up 8052 using external interupt : problems

Tags: 8051

Heres the procedure I followed

I set an edge triggered external interrupt.

```
 SET IT0 
 SETB EX0
 SETB EA
```

Then I set the PCON

```
  MOV PCON, #02H
```

When the external interupt is applied (a high to low signal) the controller is comming out of power down mode, the code that follows the above PCON code works, but the internal timmer interrupt remains off and when the controller then powers down, it never comes out of it, unless a reset is done.

PS: I am using LDR and a voltage divider circuit and a transistor as the external trigger circuit. The 'LDR Memory' is causing problems, but I am not sure the above mentioned anomalies is a result of that.

PS: The microcontroller is AT89S52 at 12 MHz.

PS: Power source is providing enough current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it can help on an input such as that LDR to have hysterisys (positive feedback).  You will need to sit down and work it out - but it means you need another transistor and a few more resistors - but it makes the circuit more reliable in operating the interrupt, and it makes the problem easier to debug - your choice as to whether you do this or not.

Next, I can't exactly answer your question BUT, what you describe can be caused by a missed interrupt.  If your code gets an interrupt, but you never return from it, it will NOT accept more interrupts until you (1) Reti or (2) Reset.

You are (2) Resetting - and it fixes the problem.

But (1) Reti is a lot easier!

The BEST solution is to find out what is causing the interrupt and fix it.  Chances are you need to disable the run flag on your timer before going to sleep.